# Why doesn't file detect the mime-type of mp3 properly?

Tags: files

Something odd I recently encountered, running `file --mime-type` on a collection of MP3 gets the mime-time wrong a third of the time:

```
$ for i in */*.mp3; do cat "$i"| file --mime-type -; done  | sort  | uniq -c
140 /dev/stdin: application/octet-stream
309 /dev/stdin: audio/mpeg
```

There doesn't seem to be any obvious reason, as even MP3s from the same source, will sometimes fail and sometimes not.

Bug, feature or anything obvious I am missing here?

Comment: I think at least a part of the problem is with your command. I suggest using find. `find . -name "*.mp3" -exec file --mime-type '{}' \; | sort | uniq -c`

Answer (score 1):

If you noticed this after an update (which sometimes happens) or after an upgrade. This would be a regression, as such is a bug and needs to be reported.

Bug reports [How do I submit a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

For reference check this posting which may be related:

http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=609211